# String diagrams in a spherical fusion category

Tags: category-theory, dual-spaces, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, fusion-categories

**1. Context**
This question is about the proof of Lemma 1.9 on page 7 of Passegger's *[Notes on Turaev-Viro-Barrett-Westbury invariants and TQFT](https://personal-homepages.mis.mpg.de/passegge/doc/turaev-viro-notes.pdf)*.
As the statement and proof of the lemma contain string diagrams (in a spherical fusion category with finite dimensional hom-spaces), I will simply post a screenshot of lemma and proof:
[image]

My understanding is the following:

- Denote by $I$ the monoidal unit of the underlying spherical fusion category $\mathbf C$. Denote by $Irr(\mathbf C)$ the set of isomorphim classes of simple objects in $\mathbf C$ (which is finite by definition of a fusion category).
  For $\{\varphi_a\}$ a basis of $Hom(I, V_n^* \otimes ... \otimes V_1^*)$ we can find its dual basis $\{\varphi_a^*\} \in Hom(I, V_1^{**} \otimes ... \otimes V_n^{**})$ with respect to the non-degenerate *canonical pairing* (defined on page 4). Because $\mathbf C$ is strict pivotal we can identify $Hom(I, V_1^{**} \otimes ... \otimes V_n^{**})$ with $Hom(I, V_1 \otimes ... \otimes V_n)$.
  The left hand side in the equality from the statement expresses the summation over two such dual bases, i.e. $\sum_{a} \varphi_a\ \otimes \varphi_a^* $. As the hom-spaces are required to be finite-dimensional this is a finite sum.

**2. Question**

- What does the sum on the left hand side in the equation in the proof denote? That is what is $\varphi$ here? How does "it" suddenly become a map in $Hom(I, V_n^* \otimes ... \otimes V_1^* \otimes X_i)$ for $i$ in the index set of $Irr(\mathbf C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is perhaps a bit misleading. Here's what actually happens. Let $\{X_i\}$ be a complete collection of simple objects, and consider a basis $\psi(i)$ of $\mathrm{Hom} (1 , V_n^\ast \otimes \ldots \otimes V_1^\ast \otimes X_i)$ for every $i$.

Then by Lemma 1.8 in the notes, one has the diagram equality as shown in the proof, but with $\varphi,\varphi^\ast$ replaced by $\psi,\psi^\ast$ for better distinction. Note that the equation holds for every disconnected subgraphs $A$, $B$, which do not play a role in the argument.

As explained in the proof, the sum collapses to a single term corresponding to $X_i = 1$, and that term involves a basis of $\mathrm{Hom} (1 , V_n^\ast \otimes \ldots \otimes V_1^\ast \otimes 1)$ and its dual basis. This is isomorphic to a basis $\varphi$ of $\mathrm{Hom} (1 , V_n^\ast \otimes \ldots \otimes V_1^\ast)$ and its dual, and so we arrive on the left-hand side of the desired equation in the lemma.